# how to express thank you to someone repeatdly help me?

Tags: phrase-request

how to express thank you to someone repeatdly help me?
For example, a man frequently try to give some help to me so many times.
or my neighbor try to share/give their food to me.
So can I say "Thank you all the time" 
Do you have a better idea or something natural in America?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one simple and fairly common way to express your gratitude to someone who has been helping you a lot:

> Thank you for all the things that you've done for me.

Or:

> Thank you for all the things that you do for me.

Comment: That also works. But the nuance here is that it sounds like you're thanking them for something that they do for your habitually. It really sounds like you two have a client/service provider relationship or something like that.

Comment: But I don't understand why this one will be closed?

Comment: When I just write question, people insist more information, context or situation to answer it exactly or properly, so I've tried to explain it specifically..but you said it is based on opinon so it will be closed...? what do I do? Can you teach me how to ASK something I wonder?

Comment: It might get closed, it might not. I don't know. It sounds like a primarily opinion-based question because depending on who's answering it the answer every time is going to be different. However, (it just downed on me) if you make it a phrase request, then I think everything will be fine.

Comment: @이관우 On Stack Exchange, good questions are on-topic. The topic here is 'learning English', but your question is more about interpersonal interactions. The choice of language doesn't seem all that important, except for the bit about America at the end. If personal interaction is the focus of your question, try asking for the question to be migrated to [Interpersonal.SE]. (I don't have a problem with your question remaining open on ELL, by the way - I'm just addressing your comment above about "how to ASK something".)

Answer (score 0):

People do say "thank you so much, for everything".  "thank you all the time" sounds awkward, though it does still convey the important thing -- that you're thanking someone strongly.